# WebAppInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat7

I'm facing the following stacktrace when running `mvn tomcat7:run`:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/blog-demo]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/blog-demo]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.replaceme.WebAppInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1670)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

This is my WebAppInitializer class:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        ConfigurableEnvironment env = rootContext.getEnvironment();
        env.setDefaultProfiles("production", env.getProperty("user.name"));

        rootContext.scan("com.replaceme.config");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

I've added a text file in `src/main/resources/META-INF/services` called `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` which contains the class identifier `com.replaceme.WebAppInitializer`.

And here are my maven dependencies:

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.13:runtime
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.13:runtime
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.7.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - version managed from 1.7.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:runtime - version managed from 1.7.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - version managed from 1.7.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:runtime - version managed from 1.7.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.16.1-GA:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.18.1-GA)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - version managed from 1.6.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - version managed from 1.6.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.2:compile
```

EDIT: It won't work with the following class as well:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        ConfigurableEnvironment env = rootContext.getEnvironment();
        env.setDefaultProfiles("production", env.getProperty("user.name"));

        rootContext.scan("com.replaceme.config");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WebApplicationInitializer (from Spring) is not a ServletContainerInitializer (from the Servlet specs). So just remove the file javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer from the services folder. Your WebAppInitializer will automatically be detected by Spring (see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html))

Comment: That's new to me but the application started.

Comment: No that's wrong. Then my WebAppInitializer will be ignored. I put some log output there and didn't get the output at the console.

Comment: How do you run your application (which server type, version etc.)? Note, that the autodetecting of a WebApplicationInitializer only works in Servlet 3.0 servers.

Comment: All information you need are provided in my question. It's Tomcat 7 (`mvn tomcat7:run`) and which Servlet version I use is provided in my list of dependencies (3.1.0).

Comment: ok, but Tomcat 7 is a Servlet 3.0 server, not Servlet 3.1 (this would be Tomcat 8). So you might have some classpath and dependency conflicts here (which could cause your error).

Answer (score 1):

Class `com.replaceme.WebAppInitializer` which extends Class `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` is not a subtype of Class `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`. So, You are not allowed to type cast an object of one type to an object of another type. To simply say you are trying to convert a dog to a donkey, that's why [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) is thrown. Casting can't be done between object types which are not in the same inheritance tree

Comment: It won't work with implemented WebApplicationInitializer instead as well (see edit above)

Comment: @dtrunk I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: A simple web application without xml configuration (java config)

Comment: This is not helpful. It's a Spring Webapp and I need to use the security stuff. So the configuration Approach is a different one.